# Redirect based upon cookie value not working on localhost

Tags: javascript, cookies

For a project I'm working on, I have to redirect a page to the correct locale version based on a cookie. What I try to do is read the cookie on init, check whether you are or are not on the correct locale page, and if not, redirect to the correct page.

Code sample:

```
if (window.location.pathname == “/website/nl.html” && locale == “fr”) {
    let redirectUrl = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname.replace(‘nl’, ‘fr’);
    redirectUrl = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname.replace(‘nl’, ‘fr’);
    console.log(redirectUrl);
    // Output: http://localhost:4502/website/fr.html
    window.location = redirectUrl;
    // Page doesn't redirect
}
if (window.location.pathname == “/website/fr.html” && locale == “nl”) {
    let redirectUrl = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname.replace(‘fr’, ‘nl’);
    redirectUrl = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname.replace(‘nl’, ‘fr’);
    console.log(redirectUrl);
    // Output: http://localhost:4502/website/nl.html
    window.location = redirectUrl;
    // Page doesn't redirect
}
```

Basically, the redirectUrl contains the correct value, but the page-url doesn't change, and it shows a blank page. Upon refreshing, you are back on the first incorrect page.

Edit: I have tried with `window.location.href = ...` and `window.location.replace(...)`

Comment: did path change?? while page get blank?

Comment: @priyanshisrivastava No, the url and it's path didn't change at all

Comment: use window .location.href in place of location.href

Comment: From the MDN page window.location - "Note that security settings, like CORS, may prevent this to effectively happen."

Comment: @sferret Shouldn't I get a CORS error in console then?

Comment: I guess so, but haven't tested it (Perhaps it doesn't so as not to give attackers a clue) I don't know